# combine tables and output without using Group By?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like some guidance on how to write the SQL for the following without using GroupBy?

Lets say I have the following table:

```
Product
PrdNo|PrdName
1|Mouse
2|Keyboard
3|Monitor
4|Speakers
5|Cpu

OrderList
OrdNo|PrdNo|Qty
101|4|2
102|3|4
103|2|1
104|1|5
105|4|3
106|5|1
107|2|4

Orders
OrdNo|OrdState
101|MD
102|CA
103|CA
104|VA
105|CA
106|NY
107|CA
```

How can display the following, for which the Orders state is CA? And Sort it ascending by product name without group by?

```
PrdName|PrdNo|OrdNo|OrdState   
Keyboard|2|103|CA
Keyboard|2|107|CA
Monitor|3|102|CA
Speakers|4|105|CA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, looks like a simple enough `join`:

```
select p.prdname, p.prdno, o.ordno, o.ordsate
from product p
   join orderlist ol on p.prdno = ol.prdno
   join orders o on ol.ordno = o.ordno
where o.ordstate = 'CA'
order by p.prdname
```

Comment: That worked like a champ! I have a follow up question: How can display the following, for which the Orders state is CA? And Sort it ascending by product name. Make it print only unique (distinct) product name. And do not use Group By command.

The output should now display:

    PrdName|PrdNo||OrdState   
    Keyboard|2|CA
    Monitor|3|CA
    Speakers|4|CA